# extracting recurring patterns from a file

Tags: awk, sed

I got a list with about 880 lines.
A example line looks like this:

> attr1=sample,attr2=sample,attr3=sample,**email=example@example.org**;**EMAIL=example@example.org**attr3=sample,attr4=sample,attr5=sample,**EMAIL=example@example.org**,attr5=sample,attr6=sample,**email=example@example.org**...

I'd like to extract only the email attributes and delete the rest. Does this work with sed?

Thank you very much and kind regards!

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you really browse a little about awk and sed?

Comment: Yes it does. If you'd like any more help then post sample input, expected output, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @hek2gml: If you're going to indent the example line as code, you have to remove the highlighting too.

Comment: Why is there no punctuation separator between the email and the 'attr3=` in the segment `EMAIL=example@example.orgattr3=sample`?  Is that a typo, or is it going to be a major problem (because if there is no separator, there is going to be a major problem). Similarly, is there any significance to the use of a semicolon to separate two `email` attributes whereas elsewhere a comma is used to separate attributes?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'attr[0-9]+=\K.*?(?=[,;]) file
```

Output:

```
sample
sample
sample
sample
sample
sample
sample
sample
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus,
Thank you very much for your reply. I've tried it with
grep -Poi email:\K.*?(?=;|$)'
and it worked almost fine. The problem is that the results are put out underneath each other. The email attributes all were in one line in the beginning, but after using this command there is a new line after a single entry. For example:
email1:a@b.c
email1:a@b.c
email1:a@b.c
email2:b@b.c
email2:b@b.c
email2:b@b.c and so on...
Is it possible to make to output look like this:
email1:a@b.c, email1:a@b.c, email1:a@b.c NEW LINE
email2:b@b.c, email2:b@b.c, email2:b@b.c?

Thank you and kind regards!

Comment: Please add your desired output for sample input (from your question) to your question.